# Using Microsoft Query from Excel to Access Query gives too many databases open error

Tags: excel, ms-access, database-connection

I have an Access database that I would like to show the resulting query from in Excel. The database pulls data from 11 linked Excel-tables that are used together with the data in Access in a lot of queries and union queries. Together this gives a resulting query that I would like to link in a new Excel spreadsheet. However when I try using Data - Get Data - Other Sources - Microsoft Query, it gives an error with too many databases open. All the data is run from Desktop on C:, and I've added the locations to the trusted paths in Excel.
I've also downloaded the Available Connections add-in, and it says I still have 212 connections left, so shoudln't be that either.

As a different approach I tried just using Get Data - Databases - Access Database, that kind of worked, but for some reason I'm missing 9 rows of data (and not ones with complicated queries). I can see 71 rows of data in Access and only 62 get imported using this method.

Are there any suggestions for how to handle the error messages or perhaps a workaround to link my Excel with Access? I would very much like for the link to be dynamic, so changes in Access is reflected in Excel with a push of the update button.

Comment: Have you tried editing Excel linked sheet via Access? Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/edit-linked-excel-data-in-access.322079/

Comment: Have you web searched topic? Some discussions attribute issue to Access update.